# i changed ($newPassword to $new), Still its empty in database!! :( ,

Tags: php, pdo

> `password is updating with empty value! old password is replaced with empty value!!

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password']; //old password
$new = $POST['new'];  //new password

//table name is users
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email_id");  
//checking email and password   
    $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(($userRow['email'] === $email)&&($userRow['password'] === $password))
    {    
        $doneQuery = $db->prepare("
        UPDATE users 
        SET password = :new   
        WHERE email = :emailid" );                                  
        $doneQuery->execute([":newPassword"=>$new,
                        ":emailid"=>$email]);
}
```

Comment: You are using non existing variable in your update query. 
`$new = $POST['new']`; is not `$newPassword` used in the query.

Comment: People asking question are insane, got answers but not marking any one. I am deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating your database using $newpassword but you declare it at the top as $new, thus meaning if is a empty variable and entering it blank 
You also missed the under score from the post 
So change

```
$new = $POST['new'];
```

To

```
$newPassword = $_POST['new'];


$email = $_POST['email']; $password = $_POST['password']; //old password         $newPassword= $_POST['new']; //new password //table name is users $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email_id"); //checking email and password $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email)); $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); if(($userRow['email'] === $email)&&($userRow['password'] === $password)) { $doneQuery = $db->prepare(" UPDATE users SET password = :newPassword WHERE email = :emailid" ); $doneQuery->execute([":newPassword"=>$new, ":emailid"=>$email]); }
```

Comment: yep i did, but not working

Comment: You also need to change SET password = :new to SET password = :newPassword